# Search Engines Bot 301 Redirect On Multi Domain Site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site with main domain `www.maindomain.com` and some parked domains as: `www.park1.com`, `www.park2.com`, etc. I want to redirect the site (all domains: main and other parked domains) to one of the parked domain, for example `www.park1.com`, only for search engines bots such as googlebot, msnbot, etc.

How can I do this using a htaccess file?

Comment: That's not a great idea - search engines will punish you if you serve different content to them than to your human visitors

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          ^(domain1|domain2|domain3).com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}    ^(Googlebot|msnbot|...)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                http://www.destination.com/$1          [R=301,L]
```